# Strange indices in chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I am using `chapterbib` to put a bibliography at the end of each chapter using:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress, sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

And i insert each bibliography with:

```
\nocite*

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{biblio}
```

My problem is that the indices of the citations are very weird! Here is what i get something like:

[image]

I'd like to have a usual numbering, with [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBkoq.jpg)], [2], [3], etc.

How can i do?

Comment: If you want numbers you don't want `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`

Answer (score 1):

You might try `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`.

The following webpage (http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) has a comparison of several popular bibliography styles.

Comment: @AlexandreWillame Great, glad to help. Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark at the top left. This way, this question can be recorded as "solved".